# Factory girl association with more than one trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have a association like this :

```
association :address, :factory => [:address, :closer_address]
```

Where my factory is like this:

```
factory :address do
  address1 "12 Any Street"
  latitude 22.4583397
  longitude -11.06776
  state 'pending_verification'

  trait :closer_address do
    latitude 33.4783397
    longitude -11.06776
  end

  trait :verified do
    state 'verified'
  end
end
```

So can I somehow create an association with more than one trait? Or there is another way around it? The idea is that I want to have `closer_address` which is also verified, and in another case I might want `closer_address` which is not verified, so that's why keeping them separate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this to have two different trait options:

```
  factory :address do
    address1 "12 Any Street"
    latitude 22.4583397
    longitude -11.06776
    state 'pending_verification'

    trait :closer_address do
      latitude 33.4783397
      longitude -11.06776
    end

    trait :verified_closer_address do
      latitude 33.4783397
      longitude -11.06776
      state 'verified'
    end
  end
```

You would create the objects like this:

```
:factory => [:address, :closer_address]
```

or this:

```
:factory => [:address, :verified_closer_address]
```

**Or** you could do this without changing your current factory:

```
  factory :address do
    address1 "12 Any Street"
    latitude 22.4583397
    longitude -11.06776
    state 'pending_verification'

    trait :closer_address do
      latitude 33.4783397
      longitude -11.06776
    end

    trait :verified do
      state 'verified'
    end
  end
```

You would create the objects like this:

```
:factory => [:address, :closer_address, :verified]
```

It is possible to use multiple traits simultaneously when creating an object with FactoryGirl.

Comment: Would have been nicer if `. . .  :factory ` was clear. what does  `...` mean?

Comment: @EmreBasala I'm pretty sure they're ellipses. I've edited the answer.